# Team name as official publish name in the Appstore?

Tags: ios, swift

Is the Team name, in my case 'thomas noname', the name which will be displayed in the appstore?
If yes: is it possible to change this name?

[Picture of Xcode Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4z4Z.jpg)

Comment: if you individual then Account name will be displayed

Comment: And what is the Account name is it like in the screenshot the Team name or where can I find it?

Comment: For individual account the name will be your real name, for companies you can use the official company name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name shown on the App Store is the individual's name on the developer account --- that cannot be changed.

Only registered corporations/LLCs can display company names on the App Store. You would need to have an incorporated company, as well as apply for a Dun & Bradstreet (D&B, or DUNS) number for verification.

More information about that: https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/

Comment: So for a individual account it is definitely NOT the Team name you see if you create a new iOS Project Example: "Team: team name (Personal Team)"?

Comment: That is correct. The team name doesn't have to do with the publishing name.